# Why can't I break or place blocks in my LAN-enabled world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I destroy or break blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-break-blocks)

I was playing Minecraft in single-player mode today when I turned on the "Open to LAN" option. I then changed my game mode to "creative" to fly back to my house, but when I turned my game mode back to "survival", I couldn't place anything down or break any blocks!

I've tried re-downloading Minecraft but that didn't help at all. It's just me in this world, so another user couldn't have changed any settings.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you set it back to survival and not adventure? Survival mode is `0`, creative is `1` and adventure is `2` IIRC.

Comment: Sounds like your house is at the origin area and you are not marked as an admin. You are unable to alter blocks within the spawn area in this case.

Comment: Sounds like adventure mode.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you put it on to Adventure Mode. Try closing it down and try it again.

Answer (score 3):

Either you are in adventure mode, or you are building/destroying in the spawn, which the game does not like.

Comment: You just need to be an op to build in the spawn.

Comment: This is only true if you are in an actual server. Otherwise spawns are not protected in Single-player. LAN is just opening a single-player world.