# I can't build or destroy anything in minecraft!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why cant i destroy blocks on minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-blocks-on-minecraft)

I am in creative mode and when i switch to survival mode i cant build or destroy anything! I am playing alone with my lan disabled.

Comment: Hi Hobbit! Could you provide more details about this? What happens when you try to destroy something (for example, does the block disappear briefly and then reappear?) Is everything working in creative mode? Is this just for particular blocks? Are you using picks/shovels or just your bare hands? Additional info may help us point you in the right direction :)

Comment: You probably switched to Adventure mode, not Survival mode.

Comment: We might be able to reopen this question if you provide more information.