# Why can't I destroy blocks in minecraft in single player mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I destroy blocks in Minecraft Single-Player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-blocks-in-minecraft-single-player)

I started playing Minecraft a few days ago, and I found that neither left click nor right click seemed to break blocks, so I can't break any blocks!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly:

You must not be in Adventure Mode, which you would have set when you started a game. Check in a new game in survival or creative mode to check that it's not this.

Secondly:

Clicking does not break (many) blocks, you need to *click and hold*. Initially only a few block types can be feasibly broken using only your hand, including dirt/grass, sand, wood and leaves, so try left-clicking and holding and see if you can break these types of blocks.

Once you've got yourself some wooden tools, you can break stone and make stone tools, etc. which will break blocks faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your having a few problem simultaneously. First of all, **right click** is the **use** command, and won't break blocks. Secondly, **left click** is the **break** command. (and sometimes use, but this is being patched out, so think of it only as break and your life will be easier.) Thirdly, to properly break a block you must aim at it, and then **HOLD** left click on your mouse. Your character should start chopping away at the block, and it will slowly break. The block will show that you are making progress by progressivly cracking up until it finally pops.

Additionally, some blocks cannot be broken without the proper tools.

Answer (score 0):

first check you controls

if that is not the problem; chances are you are in adventure mode, you need to be in survival mode

if you have cheats enabled press `/` and type `gamemode survival`

otherwise create a new world and ensure the game mode button says survival