# Why can't I break blocks in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I destroy or break blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-break-blocks)

after playing in creative for a little bit, I went back to survival and found that I could not damage or break any block without the tool best suited for the job.  IE I cannot break dirt with anything but a shovel.  This problem has so far only occurred on SMP and is not a problem with my single player world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have switched yourself into adventure mode rather than survival mode. Adventure mode is like survival mode, except that it does not allow breaking blocks without the specific tools, thus, for example, preventing the player from digging around puzzle areas in custom maps.

The command for survival mode is `/gamemode 0` (1 is creative, 2 is adventure).