# Blocks Keep Breaking When I Try to Build!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to set a block down or add a block to water or land - it doesn't really seem to matter where - they're breaking.  It's like I'm digging when I'm not.  I'm in Creative Mode and have been building all kinds of stuff (I'm pretty limited in my designs... still learning).  It just started doing it not too long ago.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may need to do to resolve the issues?

Comment: You seem to be having the opposite problem to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-place-blocks?rq=1), but some of the causes might be the same.  I assume you're playing on single player, though, right?

Comment: Do you mean that when you place a block, it breaks, or that when you try to place blocks you break existing blocks instead?

Comment: Are you in a protected area?

Comment: Question needs more detail. Are you; in single player? have any mods installed?  On windows/linux/mac/console? From the sound of it, it would seem you have your mouse buttons inverted.

Comment: If you are on Mac, the default setting is for the mouse to be all left-click and no right-click. If you have been building, then it has been working, but if you for some reason changed it back, then that's what is causing the issue (if it is Mac).

Comment: Try the other mouse button

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with your controls. Go to options > controls > and check the attack/destroy and use item/place block controls. Keep in mind that button 1 is left click and button 2 is right click.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Mouse settings and make sure your primary button is left click. I had inverted my mouse controls to use my mouse left-handed.