# Minecraft mined block reappears and other problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I break a block in the latest Minecraft it reappears; around 10 seconds later and often not at all. I am on single player and I am not using mods. I also have tried going into creative and it works fine, but it doesn't work in survival (I am definitely in survival not adventure). It only happens on this particular world. All mobs tend to be frozen or move slowly like a zombie with slowness 3. My settings are all off or lowest (except VPO as I read it helps) and I have 9 chunk render distance and 60 Max FPS. If I hit a zombie I don't take damage and if I punch him it stays in the air for 3 seconds.
It is much worse when using LAN. How can I fix this? This only happens for one world.

Also the other post similar to this isn't the same as in my world I'm definitely in the correct gamemode (I did /gamemode s) and I have also added more details on other lag on my world as well. I can place blocks fine.

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I destroy or place blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-place-blocks)

Comment: How else will I get help? By saying "help me I cant do minecraft" or do I do noting and never find out what?

Comment: Well if it is a SUPPOSED duplicate then atleast someone else has the same prblem

Comment: ... Seems like a blaringly obvious **Get a better computer** or, **Get a better server**. (Could we get your computer specs?)

Comment: Are you saying this happens in single player?

Comment: Happens in singleplayer I'm not on server and also I'm not buying a new computer for a problem I know is fixable

Comment: UNCLER? ITS CLEARER THAN ANYTHING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when playing on singleplayer, the game runs separately as a server and a client. When the server is lagging behind, you may notice:

1. Blocks reappearing after being mined
2. Vehicles such as boats and horses being very slow to control
3. Items taking a while to pick up
4. Delay in executing commands
5. Mobs moving and pathfinding slowly
6. Plants growing slowly
7. Day-night cycle going slowly

Having a good FPS just indicates that the client part of the game is not lagging, but the server part can still be lagging in the background. Whereas high graphic settings will cause the client to lag, different things can cause the server to lag:

1. Intensive commands (such as `/fill`) repeating on a clock
2. Lots of entities in the world
3. Large number of chunks loaded (E.G: From chunk-loaders)
4. Slow computer
5. Large redstone contraptions (especially if they're moving blocks around)

You should work at fixing these causes to help stop the lag in your world. If you gave a world download I could look at it and see if anything in particular is causing an issue, otherwise, you should be able to:

1. Disable any command clocks and redstone you have active
2. Use commands or a tool such as [MCEdit](https://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/) to clear up entities
3. Remove any chunk loaders, lower your render distance
4. Upgrade your computer (you probably don't want to do this)

Comment: Thanks! That has helped a lot :D you're a true lifesaver!

Comment: @EnderGeorge44 You can press the tick next to the question to accept it as working.

Comment: done and the tick is next to your answer