# Why can't I break blocks in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I played Herobrine Mansion, I could not break any blocks. Why is that?

I tried to change my controls; I Googled everything. I also can't hold down Mouse Button 1 to keep swinging my sword. I tried switching game modes, but I don't have the commands.

Comment: Hope you try to kill **him** with the right tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I destroy or place blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-place-blocks)

Answer (score 3):

Adventure mode is not the same as Survival mode. In adventure mode, you cannot break blocks at all. Its designed for adventure maps.

If you are in a single player world, go into your options and open your world to LAN, making sure to turn cheats on. Then type "/gamemode 0" in the chat. After that, you should be able to break blocks.