# Can break but not place Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I paid for *Minecraft* on the mac and I can't place blocks that I break.

Someone said the same thing and their problem was with the Magic Mouse and while do I need a new mouse I've tried using command click and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Command-click doesn't right click, Control-click does. Also, what has "Place block" been set to in your controls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I destroy or place blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-place-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

Check your control bindings and make sure your place block key isn't bound to something else.