# Why can't I break blocks but can place blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was building and I must have clicked something because I couldn’t break blocks but I could place them. I don’t know if this means something but I was playing Crazycraft.

I tried looking through options but nothing seems to work and I can’t find any videos about this.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I destroy or place blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82362/4797)

Answer (score 4):

You probably activated adventure mode. To disable it, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and go to settings. Then click on personal mode and change to survival/creative - whatever you want.

Comment: Or if you have commands active, you can use `/gamemode s` for survival, or `/gamemode c` for creative