# I can't seem to break blocks in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My nephew got a hold of my laptop while I was playing Minecraft and he pressed on random keys, and now I can't break any blocks.

None of the suggestions or answers I've found so far have worked. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting minecraft?

Comment: Hmm.. what key prevents blocks from being broken? None, as far as I know. What gamemode are you in?

Comment: What happens when you come up to a block and hold left mouse button? You hold it, not click rapidly, right?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why can't I break or place blocks in my LAN enabled world?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79868/why-cant-i-break-or-place-blocks-in-my-lan-enabled-world?rq=1) & [Why can't I destroy or break blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-or-break-blocks)

Comment: Have you checked the controls in options? Make sure the attack control is set to mouse button 1...

Comment: Your question would be a lot better if you listed what you had tried.

Comment: this happened to me once... it was some setting or game-mode...

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that your gamemode is not set to adventure mode.

- for regular survival mode enter : `/gamemode s`
- for creative mode enter : `/gamemode c`
- for adventure mode enter: `/gamemode a`

Survival mode is just the Minecraft as everybody knows it and this is probably the mode you want to be changing to.

Creative is the mode in which you have unlimited blocks and resources to build everything in your imagination. You also have the ability to fly.

Adventure mode is the same as survival only you don't have the ability to destroy any blocks without the correct tool.

---

If you are playing on a multiplayer server you might be building or changing to close to spawn. Try walking in one direction for a few seconds and try it again then.

---

Also clicking does not break (many) blocks, you need to click and hold. Initially only a few block types can be feasibly broken using only your hand, including dirt/grass, sand, wood and leaves, so try left-clicking and holding and see if you can break these types of blocks.

---

Finally, check if you have "touchscreen mode" enabled under control settings. This can often mess with block breaking.

Comment: I think the too close to spawn is the likely issue.

Comment: @tombull89, what are the implications of being close to the spawn? I assume you mean original spawn site - I've never had problems breaking blocks there.

Comment: @Cyclops I recall if you're too close to the spawn area (within 16 blocks) you can't break items...but I've just realised that's online, not in single-player.

Comment: If you are playing SMP (i.e. multiplayer), the server can have spawn protection, but if playing SSP (singleplayer) there is **no spawn protection**.

Comment: @AlvinWong this is true only Creepingturtle does not say if its on sp or mp. Ill add your comment to my answer though.